# CSS sliding nav direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a nav that uses CSS and a bit of JQuery to slide out from the left. Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/CdY5P/2/

I now want the top left button that opens the slide out menu to be on the top right and for the menu to slide out from the right rather than the left.
I have tried editing several elements, particularly the `translate3d` property but no luck :(

Also, it currently pushes the content across, I wanted it sitting on top of the content when it slides out (menu on top of the page).

Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: The main class that's added does the following transforms when showing the nav.

```
.csstransforms3d.csstransitions .show-nav #inner-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code here and don't sidestep the SO rule of posting code when linking to jsFiddle.net.

Comment: No problem @j08691 I'll add it in.

Comment: The problem is that a typical slideout changes width/height only (to/from 0).. That means top and left are easy but right or bottom will require a simultaneous move and resize.

Comment: Thanks @Harry I'll trim it down now and update the question with the new post.

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie - any chance you can provide assistance?

Comment: @Harry: Trimmed down :) sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/CdY5P/2/

Comment: @Harry: Well, I feel bad asking for help and loading the fiddle with too much, so you were correct in asking for a trimmed down version. Feel free to check it out and provide any assistance :) Thanks

Comment: No problem, would be great if someone could assist though :)

Comment: Looking at it now, but already some unrelated weirdness... You seem to be enabling touch based on a hard-wired window size instead of touch availability... ARGH!!!

Comment: Obviously for mobile devices but yep can use touch availability.. any easy way of changing this to "right to left" slide out with a way to slide over the content instead of pushing content across? using `absolute`? Feel free to play with the fiddle, thanks :)

Comment: I can make my desktop browser less than 797px. Please don't use window size to assume mobile/touch :)

Comment: Can you please rip out all CSS not directly related to the problem? It is still over 300 lines and not obvious what is used/not used.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: You online? If so, I'll happily strip everything unrelated out in a few minutes.